# gr-osmosdr Could NOT find Boost (C++ libraries)

Tags: fedora, c++

End goal: Play about with RTL-SDR in GNURadio Companion

While following the instructions on [this page](http://sdr.osmocom.org/trac/wiki/rtl-sdr), I've run into errors concerning the Boost C++ libraries. While building the gr-osmosdr blocks to use in GNURadio, cmake fails to complete because it cannot find Boost which is definately installed. Version 1.57.

```
Last metadata expiration check performed 1:27:21 ago on Thu Jul 28 15:01:40 2016.
Package boost-1.57.0-6.fc22.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Specifically, the error message I receive looks like...

```
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Build type not specified: defaulting to release.
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.4.11") 
-- Extracting version information from git describe...
-- Configuring Boost C++ Libraries...
-- Could NOT find Boost
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:125 (message):
  Boost required to build gr-osmosdr
```

The code in CMakeLists.txt concerning Boost is...

```
########################################################################
# Setup boost
########################################################################
MESSAGE(STATUS "Configuring Boost C++ Libraries...")

# Although not required on my system, some users have linking issues without
SET(BOOST_REQUIRED_COMPONENTS
    thread
    system
)

if(UNIX AND NOT BOOST_ROOT AND EXISTS "/usr/lib64")
    list(APPEND BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "/usr/lib64") #fedora 64-bit fix
endif(UNIX AND NOT BOOST_ROOT AND EXISTS "/usr/lib64")

set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS
    "1.35.0" "1.35" "1.36.0" "1.36" "1.37.0" "1.37" "1.38.0" "1.38" "1.39.0" "1.39"
    "1.40.0" "1.40" "1.41.0" "1.41" "1.42.0" "1.42" "1.43.0" "1.43" "1.44.0" "1.44"
    "1.45.0" "1.45" "1.46.0" "1.46" "1.47.0" "1.47" "1.48.0" "1.48" "1.49.0" "1.49"
    "1.50.0" "1.50" "1.51.0" "1.51" "1.52.0" "1.52" "1.53.0" "1.53" "1.54.0" "1.54"
    "1.55.0" "1.55" "1.56.0" "1.56" "1.57.0" "1.57" "1.58.0" "1.58" "1.59.0" "1.59"
    "1.60.0" "1.60" "1.61.0" "1.61" "1.62.0" "1.62" "1.63.0" "1.63" "1.64.0" "1.64"
    "1.65.0" "1.65" "1.66.0" "1.66" "1.67.0" "1.67" "1.68.0" "1.68" "1.69.0" "1.69"
)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS ${BOOST_REQUIRED_COMPONENTS})

if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Boost required to build " ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
endif()

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK)
```

Probably just have to point one thing to another. But I don't know which to what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule in Fedora, packages include runtime libraries but not header information and other things you might need to compile against them. For that, you need the corresponding `-devel` package.

In this case:

```
sudo dnf install boost-devel
```

should do it.

Comment: Yep. That did it. Thanks for the general rule tip.